# clistbox gettext error

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to add items from alistbox to cstringarray. But text is null always. plz suggest the changes

```
 int count = m_OutList.GetCount();



for ( i = 0; i <m_OutList.GetCount(); i++)
    {
        m_OutList.GetText( buf[i], text );
        m_selcomponents->Add(text);

//      getb  //Add();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `text` is a CString in your example, you need to write `m_OutList.GetText(i,text)` - you don't need a buffer variable if you pass a CString&. `buf[i]` is a part of your buffer and has a random value.